# dense_rank() and max, which one is better to find Nth highest salary (return null if no result)

Tags: mysql, sql, max, dense-rank

e.g N is 2, I can either use densr_rank() or max to find second highest salary from Employee table.

```
select max(salary) as SecondHighestSalary from employee 
where salary < (select max(salary) from employee)
```

above query works perfect, given the condition that if there is no second highest salary in the table, it returns NULL.

However I can achieve the similar results using dense_rank() function such as:

```
select e.salary as SecondHighestSalary 
from (
      select salary, dense_rank() OVER (order by salary desc) dr from employee) e
where dr = 2
```

above query works fine given there is ONLY one second highest salary in the table, if the table has salaries `[300, null, null]` its returning `[null, null]`, I need only one answer in the result set. how can I achieve that ?

follow up to the question: in this case, which is better (in terms of memory/processing time)
max or dense_rank ()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really interesting question.  You haven't specified the database.  But if I assume that you have an index on `salary` that can be used by the query (so possibly `salary desc` depending on the database).  Then your first query might have really good performance:

- Fetch the match salary using the index.
- Start scanning the index for values less than the max.
- Short circuit the scan because you get the max right away.

I'm not promising that all databases would generate this plan, but two index lookups would typically be faster than `dense_rank()` in this case.

Of course, with any question like this, you should test on your data and your database.  That is really the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query with max would only work with N = 2, so it is bad solution, but it should be better in terms of performance than second query with `dense_rank`.

I would suggest another approach: fetch only N first rows ordering by `salary` descending. Then, from this result get the lowest salary.

Fetching N rows should be lightning fast if you have index on `salary` column. Then having "only" N rows, it should be also fast to fetch the last record.

So query should look like (for SQL Server):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
    SELECT TOP N * FROM SalaryTable ORDER BY salary DESC
) ORDER BY salary;
```

For those RDBMS which have `LIMIT N` instead of `SELECT TOP N`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM SalaryTable ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT N
) ORDER BY salary LIMIT 1;
```